# What should I consider when choosing an OpenGL version for simple rendering tasks?

Tags: opengl, compatibility

I have an application in which I want to draw some simple 3D geometry to the screen - a relatively small number of textured triangles with no shading. I have decided to use OpenGL.

The application doesn't need any features which are not available in OpenGL 1.1, so any OpenGL version is sufficient.

What should I consider when deciding which OpenGL version to use?

Answer (score 1):

There is little to no reason to use OGL 1.1, other than if you want to prototype something or if you are doing something extremely simple. VBOs are introduced in OGL 1.5 and thats probably the lowest I would be willing to go. You get shaders in version 2. That is usually not a bad place to aim for. OGL 3 gives you VAOs which can really simplify draw calls, instanced rendering, and uniform and texture buffer objects which are really useful for more complex tasks.

If you want something real quick and dirty OGL 1.1 is fine. Usually I would not suggest going under 1.5 as VBOs are not too much of a jump and can really make your code a lot easier to debug and VBOs are much more efficient.

All in all i would suggest using OGL2 so you can use the programmable pipeline to handle your own matrices efficiently so you don't have to do all the push/pop matrices which can make your head spin in a complicated rendering situation. If using OGL3 isn't a problem then you could also use VAOs to make things even cleaner. This also gives you a bit more freedom if you decide you need more power/features later on.